# VPN connection not showing under dail-up and VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have a laptop with Windows Seven with two VPN access correctly configured (Agence Quadra Diffusion and Publimat in the image below). They are both showing under the "dail-up and VPN" part in the Network control panel of the systray.

Yesterday I added a new VPN connection (VME) and it went well except for the fact that this connection does not show under the "dail-up and VPN".

As you can see in the image below my VPN connection, when connected, appear as a new network (VME 2 under connected to) and so I can't disconnect it directly from the panel. I also have to connect it manually by going in the advanced parameter of the network control panel.

I have installed OpenVPN if it matters.

Thanks in advance

As I'm not allowed to post an image, the image is available here : http://blog.slucas.fr/_media/network.png

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the noise.

A simple reboot fixed the problem.